# XAML TextBlock: How to make TextBlock have variable height?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, textblock

I have a ListBox that contains TextBlocks.

Sometimes the content of a TextBlock is too long and I want the height of this entry to double or triple as needed to accommodate the text.

I tried TextWrapping="Wrap" but it doesn't work. Every TextBlock is still just one line in height.

Is there an easy way to fix the problem in XAML? Thanks.

*** Additional info: I tried to simplify the question but perhaps the complete scenario is better.

1. I have a listbox whose entries are displayed according to a template in code below.
2. Each entry has 2 pieces of info: a product price followed by product name.
3. I don't want to use the horizontal scrollbar in the listbox and want the product name to be displayed in 2 or more lines if necessary. The product name is the 2nd TextBlock.

Here's my XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock MinWidth="40"  TextAlignment="Right" Text = "{Binding ProductPrice}" />


                    <TextBlock Text = "{Binding ProductName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `StackPanel`. Try using `DockPanel`:

```
<DockPanel>
 <TextBlock  DockPanel.Dock="Left" MinWidth ="40"  TextAlignment="Right" Text = "11.12" />
 <TextBlock Text = "{Binding LongText}" DockPanel.Dock="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
</DockPanel>
```

**For Example:**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Disable the listbox horizontal `scrollViewer`. This way the `textBlock` will be forced to wrap.

XAML:

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</ListBox>
```

Example result:

[image]

**Edit:**

From the XAML you added I'm confident that the problem lays in the `StackPanel`.
Try replacing it with `Grid` for example:

```
    <ListBox Name="listBox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <Grid>
                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock MinWidth="40"  TextAlignment="Right" Text = "{Binding ProductPrice}" />


                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text = "{Binding ProductName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />

                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
```

`StackPanel` doesn't limit the content size, therefore the `textBlock` doesn't knows where the space ends , and the wrapping doesn't happens.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. As is, the listbox doesn't have a horizontal scrollbar so making the horizontal scrollbar invisible doesn't change anything.

Comment: @user776676: Can you please add your XAML to the question? It will be easier to find the issue.

Comment: Thanks, Michael, I've just added the XAML.

Comment: @user776676: please see my edit. I'll add the full xaml as well in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

this will help you do that. Dont Size the `TextBlock` just size the scroll viewer because texblock needs to be variable so `ScrollViewer` will apply `Scrollbar` once it goes beyond the size of `ScrollViewer` .

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <TextBlock/>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

For ListBoxItem

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.Items>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LongText}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </ListBox.Items>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for presenting the option of using the horizontal scrollbar. But I don't want to scroll horizontally. I want the height of each of the listbox item to adjust automatically to fit the text.